# Windows Phone 7 - Available WCF bindings

Tags: wcf, binding, windows-phone-7, wcf-binding

I've been looking for documentation on the WCF Bindings supported by WP7 for a while and can't seem to find it. Can someone post a link to any documentation available they find. If it's from Microsoft (MSDN) even better.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search is your friend, even on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-GB?query=%2Bwp7%20%2Bwcf&ac=8) ;)

UPDATE: Bing is also a good search tool. First result for [+wp7 +wcf +supported +bindings](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%2Bwp7+%2Bwcf+%2Bsupported+%2Bbindings&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC) gives this article: [What is not supported in WCF for Windows Phone?](http://live.mscommunity.net/blogs/damirdobric/archive/2010/06/05/what-is-not-supported-in-wcf-for-windows-phone.aspx)

Comment: Still can't find any documentation.

Comment: I've added some more information to my original answer, which chould give you some specific help.

Answer (score 3):

I failed at finding a list on MSDN, so I just went through all of the bindings and looked at the supported frameworks.

WP7

- BasicHttpBinding (7.0)

SL:

- BasicHttpBinding (3)
- PollingDuplexBinding (5)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2009/03/20/what-s-new-with-web-services-in-silverlight-3-beta.aspx) for some reference. I would **strongly recommend** using basicHttpBinding for services that you want to access from Windows Phone 7, since you might encounter some problems with others (e.g. wsHttpBinding is not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft OData is easy to implement and its REST

Comment: http://www.odata.org/developers another one http://wildermuth.com/2010/08/09/Using_OData_with_Windows_Phone_7_SDK_Beta hope that helps

Comment: OData has a pretty narrow scope though. If you happen to want to expose your database for CRUD access, it's OK. (And if you're building what amount to Access client/server applications migrated to the cloud, then it's probably ideal.) But if you want anything else - either a REST resource architecture that isn't just a bunch of database tables, or if REST isn't actually a good fit (which is often true; REST is fashionable, but it's not a size that fits all problems) then in my experience using OData with WP7 is a major hassle.

Comment: Hmm ok, Thanks for the infomarion Ian.