# Accessing a non silverlight enabled web service from a Silverlight Phone Application

Tags: windows, silverlight, web-services, windows-phone-7, wcf-endpoint

I'm trying to access a WCF web service (that is NOT silverlight enabled) from a Windows Phone Application using Silverlight. 
I am able to add the service reference fine and I can see all the methods on that service.

The problem I'm having is that when I actually try to call a method I get an "EndPointNotFoundException."

I've read many examples that use a web service which is SilverLight enabled.

My question is: **Is it possible to use a web service that is NOT silverlight enabled in a Windows Phone Application using Silverlight?**

Comment: Have you set the cross domain policy on the web service?

Comment: Yeah I have set the policy as per this site: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=VS.95).aspx) I still get the following error when using a Windows Phone Application client: "There was no endpoint listening at "XXXXX" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action."

Comment: @ScottFerguson No, I never did figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Test the service with the WCF Test Client and see if it works. In case there are no errors, make sure that the service is using basicHttpBinding (and not wsHttpBinding, as I see in a lot of services - it is [not supported on WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888358/windows-phone-7-available-wcf-bindings/4890415#4890415)).

Comment: I did try out the app but I did already know it was working because I have another .NET application using the service.  It works great except for this scenario where I'm trying to use the service in a "SilverLight Windows Phone Application." And yes, the service is using basicHttpBinding.